# Dual monitor resolution is ok, but display is stretched in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: monitor, display-resolution

i have a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10, with a dual monitor setup on a Nvidia GT620. Both monitors are  Samsung SyncMaster S23B350, left monitor is with on a VGA to DVI adapter, and the right monitor is in the VGA output.

The left monitor resolution is 1920x1080_60.00, but the image is stretched, see the image.

[image]

Xrandr output is

```
cristian@cristian-desktop:~/.config$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96* 
   1920x1360_60.00  59.96  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08
```

I try to fix this using the built in monitor settings, but i can't adjust the widht or the height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers version (as of writing this today ... it is version 355.11).

Open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
sudo reboot
```

In case you use a computer with a switchable graphics solution install Optimus support as well :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

Note : If you had proprietary NVIDIA driver already installed you should remove them before ...

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```